# CKEDITOR - how to add permanent onclick event?

Tags: events, ckeditor

I am looking for a way to make the CKEDITOR wysiwyg content interactive. This means for example adding some onclick events to the specific elements. I can do something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].document.getById('someid').setAttribute('onclick','alert("blabla")');
```

After processing this action it works nice. But consequently if I change the mode to source-mode and then return to wysiwyg-mode, the javascript won't run. The onclick action is still visible in the source-mode, but is not rendered inside the textarea element.

However, it is interesting, that this works fine everytime:

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].document.getById('id1').setAttribute('style','cursor: pointer;');
```

And it is also not rendered inside the textarea element! How is it possible? What is the best way to work with onclick and onmouse events of CKEDITOR content elements?

I tried manually write this by the source-mode:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            This is some <strong id="id1" onclick="alert('blabla');" style="cursor: pointer;">sample text</strong>. You are using <a href="http://ckeditor.com/">CKEditor</a>.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the Javascript (onclick action) does not work. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

My final solution:

```
               editor.on('contentDom', function() {
                var elements = editor.document.getElementsByTag('span');
                for (var i = 0, c = elements.count(); i < c; i++) {
                    var e = new CKEDITOR.dom.element(elements.$.item(i));
                    if (hasSemanticAttribute(e)) {
                        // leve tlacitko mysi - obsluha
                        e.on('click', function() {
                            if (this.getAttribute('class') === marked) {
                                if (editor.document.$.getElementsByClassName(marked_unique).length > 0) {
                                    this.removeAttribute('class');
                                } else {
                                    this.setAttribute('class', marked_unique);
                                }
                            } else if (this.getAttribute('class') === marked_unique) {
                                this.removeAttribute('class');
                            } else {
                                this.setAttribute('class', marked);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Filtering (only CKEditor >=4.1)

This attribute is removed because CKEditor does not allow it. This filtering system is called Advanced Content Filter and you can read about it here:

- http://ckeditor.com/blog/Upgrading-to-CKEditor-4.1
- http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released
- [Advanced Content Filter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)

In short - you need to configure editor to allow `onclick` attributes on some elements. For example:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraAllowedContent: 'strong[onclick]'
} );
```

Read more here: [`config.extraAllowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent).

#### `on*` attributes inside CKEditor

CKEditor encodes `on*` attributes when loading content so they are not breaking editing features. For example, `onmouseout` becomes `data-cke-pa-onmouseout` inside editor and then,  when getting data from editor, this attributes is decoded.

There's no configuration option for this, because it wouldn't make sense.

**Note**: As you're setting attribute for element inside editor's editable element, you should set it to the protected format:

```
element.setAttribute( 'data-cke-pa-onclick', 'alert("blabla")' );
```

#### Clickable elements in CKEditor

If you want to observe click events in editor, then this is the correct solution:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    var element = editor.document.getById( 'foo' );
    editor.editable().attachListener( element, 'click', function( evt ) {
        // ...

        // Get the event target (needed for events delegation).
        evt.data.getTarget();
    } );
} );
```

Check the documentation for [`editor#contentDom` event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) which is very important in such cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am using ice:inputRichText which includes CKEDITOR version 3.x. I am not sure if there is such a property...

Comment: Ok, then there's no ACF :P It was introduced in CKEditor 4.1.

Comment: Everything I need is: clickable elements in CKEDITOR content. Is it possible to make it by handling some CKEDITOR events? (maybe this: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.dom.event.html#getTarget)

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want clickable elements inside editor, then you'll be interested in attaching `click` to http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-editable and checking target. I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: But this is also for the version 4, isn't it? (editable() function)

Comment: I have solved it - thanks to Reinmar!!! You have made my day :-)). Everything I must have done is this: add the onclick event-handling to the contentDom.

Comment: Reinmar, you mention checking the target after attaching click to the editable. In my case I don't see a target in the event object. Could you specify where to look for the target? Thanks

Comment: I see event.data.$.currentTarget but that appears to be the editor itself. Not the element I clicked on. Maybe I attached the listener incorrectly. I did `editable.attachListener(editable, 'click', function(event) {` instead of passing the element.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to show how to get the event target. The target will be the node that was clicked.

Comment: @Reinmar can you please help me for my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458337/onclick-function-not-work-in-ckeditor

Comment: I have to add (click) instead of onclick How do I add in Ckeditor