# OnMouseOver event in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, onmouseover

I use the WYSIWYG editor CKEditor. I have a div element that has an onMouseOver attribute but when it is in the editor, my onMouseOver attribute change in data-cke-pa-onmouseover. I searched but I found nothing. Do you know how to make my onMouseOver attribute is not changed?

my div in the editor:

```
<div id="253" class="data-video" data-cke-pa-onmouseover="CKEditorHoverVideo('id', true)">
```

desired code:

```
<div id="253" class="data-video" onmouseover="CKEditorHoverVideo('id', true)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor secures a lot of things when parsing the content that it gets. It secures element events (like `onclick`), javascript (`<script>` wrapped in `<!-- ... -->`), iframes etc. just make sure they don't break editor internals, which is, of course undesired.

You have to attach your JavaScript events after editor contents are loaded (i.e [`contentDom`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-contentDom) or [`setData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-setData), `afterPaste` events) to get it working. Most likely, you should develop your [own plugin](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro) that automates this process.

Comment: Check also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event/17051511#17051511