# Ckeditor:call a function on mouseover to a link in editor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have to create a plugin that can produce the following markup

```
<a  id='location' onmouseover="win(this)" href="#">Cityname</a>
```

for this I have made this plugin

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'geoloc',
{
    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.addCommand( 'link',
            {
                exec : function( editor )
                {    
                    style = new CKEDITOR.style(

                            {

                            element : 'span',

                            attributes : {  'id' : 'location' , 'onmouseover' : 'win(this)' , 'href' : '#'},

                        });

                                    style.apply(editor.document);
                }
            });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Geoloc',
        {
            label: 'Add to geomap',
            command: 'link',
            icon: this.path + 'newplugin.png'
        } );
    }
} );
```

Problem:
It adds `span` tag as style but not `anchor` tag which I need.

Question:
How can I call `win()` method `onmouseover` to that link in the editor.? Where to put that methods code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event/17051511#17051511

Comment: @Reinmar, thanx i'll check that answer. But I don't understand why It is adding span but when I add anchor tag it doesnot ??