# Onclick function not work in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4.5.1  version , I used CK Editor for view purpose and in that I putted some onclick function for showing some detail run time as

```
<img onclick="callFun(this)" src="/abc/xyx.gif" />
```

But now when content load on CKEditor it convert my onclick function to

```
<img data-cke-saved-src="/abc/xyx.gif" src="/abc/xyx.gif"  data-cke-pa-onclick="callFun(this)">
```

As you can see above it convert my onclick function to data-cke-pa-onclick function.

I instantiate CKEditor as below,

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'domTextArea',{
    allowedContent: true
} );
```

Please guide me for this.
I also tried [CKEDITOR - how to add permanent onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event) but could not success .

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event

Comment: @Farhan I already tried it but fail.

Comment: This is a DUP of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event/17051511.