# CKeditor - html Onclick property is not working

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm using the code below to open google in new window but in CKeditor this doesn't work.

```
<div align="center"><button onclick="window.open('http://google.com','_self')">Click here to open <b> google </b> 
</button></div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to:

```
<div align="center"><!--                              ▾ Here -->
    <button onclick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank')">
        Click here to open <b> google </b> 
    </button>
</div>
```

The `_blank` let's the browser know it had to go into a new window.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3938f0a/) example

**EDIT**

Try taking a look here: [CKEDITOR - how to add permanent onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for Your reply! but it didn't work with CKeditor. Currently I'm using CKeditor v4.4 and I'm not sure if it is something related to their ACF feature.

Answer (score 1):

Change _self to _blank

```
    <div align="center"><button onclick="window.open('http://google.com','_blank')">Click here to open <b> google </b>
    </button></div>
```

This should work.