# Assigning events to span elements in CKEditor's textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, dom-events, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to bind an event to each sentence that is entered in the CKEditor's textarea. I split the sentences and then add `<span>` tags to delimit the sentences assigning each sentence a unique 1-indexed ID (i.e.: so the first sentence has an ID of: "sen_1").

I believe that I am selecting the sentences successfully since I can log them to the console. However, I cannot seem to assign them events.

```
var el = CKEDITOR.instances.rawText.document.getById('sen_1');
    if (el !== null) {
        // not used, el is an object, e is just the span element and its contents
        var e = el['$'];
        el.on('click', function() {
            alert('I should see this');
        });
    }
```

I have tried tweaking the above code, but have not had any success. I have tried changing the event from 'click' to various other methods (I will eventually change this to a delayed hover, but I wanted to get the event binding sorted first), but have not had any success.

It's such a small amount of code that I have a feeling that I am missing something obvious, but haven't been able to track down what it is yet.

EDIT: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event/17051511#17051511), which seems like it could solve my problem of adding events to `<span>` tags. However, the `contentDom` event is not firing.

```
var userText = CKEDITOR.instances.rawText;

userText.on( 'change', function() {

    ...
    // get text from CKEditor
    // wrap each sentence in <span> tags (I want events bound to these)
    // setData of CKEditor as the sentences wrapped
    // ajax calls to MongoDB to store sentence info
    ...

    userText.on( 'contentDom', function() {
        var el = userText.document.getById('sen_1');
        console.log(el);
        userText.editable().attachListener( el, 'click', function(e) {
            alert("See?");
            e.data.getTarget();
        });
    });
```

}

I don't see `el` being logged and I can't find any `contentDom` event in either Chrome or Safari's dev tools. I currently have this inside of a

Any ideas on what could be causing `contentDom` to not fire? I realize that `contentDom` should fire when the editor content is ready. I tried putting the `contentDom` event outside of the `change` event and it worked there. However, it is pretty much useless to me there as the number of `<span>` tags will be changing as the user input changes.

Comment: Try event delegation. Listen on the editable element (`editor.editable()`) and check the event target.

Comment: I found an answer that seems like it could solve adding events to my spans here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045329/ckeditor-how-to-add-permanent-onclick-event/17051511#17051511.

However, for some reason, the 'contentDom' event is not firing. I have edited my post for further detail.